# How to get in-line location using google-maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, coordinates

There is a problem with getting my in-line position in google-maps. Method "getLastKnownLocation" isn't suitable for me.
I just need to turn on GPS and find my location in the same way as it is in google map programm.

Is there some another ways how to do that?

Comment: u want gps turn on code or what???

Comment: What is an "in-line position in google-maps"? Why is `getLastKnownLocation()` not "suitable" for you? Did you read [the "Location Data" page in the Maps V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location)? If you did, what specific problems did you encounter when following their instructions?

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() sometimes returns "null" and map is empty

Comment: any location listener you get can return null, that means you dont have lock on your location. You need to handle a situation like that in your code